# Laravel - pivot data not available in email

Tags: laravel, email, model, pivot-table

I have the relations in the models as follows:

```
class HotelBooking extends Model
{    
    public function rooms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Room', 'hotelbooking_room', 'hotelbooking_id')->withPivot(['quantity', 'addon_id']);
    }
}
```

When I call `$booking->rooms()->get();`, I should get the following data:

```
"rooms": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "hotel_id": 89,
            "type": "Double",
            "quantity": 4,
            "adults": 2,
            "children": 1,
            "description": null,
            "created_at": "2016-05-15 12:24:39",
            "updated_at": "2016-05-15 15:29:58",
            "pivot": {
                "hotelbooking_id": 30,
                "room_id": 28,
                "quantity": 1,
                "addon_id": 386
            }
        }
    ]
```

Which is normally correct. What's weird is that when I send `$rooms` to the email data, the `pivot` attribute is not sent. It works well along the website but in case of sending it in the email it does not. Any idea why?!

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add the code which doesn't work to your post.

Comment: @JoelHinz The code works as mentioned but part of the data is sent fetched. That's what I explained when I call $booking->rooms()->get()